# Keep keyboard visible in onResume mode in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Hi I have a entry in a page, I want to show the entry keyboard in every page load event. Currently the entry keyboard focus is working in first page load. But it is not working when app came from sleep mode.

I have tried the below , but not working. Please help me

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        
        base.OnAppearing();
        ent.Focus();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When app re-opens after sleep mode (or switch from desktop or another app), that is handled by `App.OnResume`.

Use `MessagingCenter` to communicate from there to the current page:

in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "WakeUp");
}
```

in `your-page.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>(this, "WakeUp", (sender) =>
    {
        // Do something here.
    });
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<App>(this, "WakeUp");
}
```

In your case, where I have `// Do something here.`, put your code:

```
ent.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me

```
            Task.Delay(500);
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async()=> 
            {               
               ent_OTP.Focus(); 
            });
```